# Google maps Ajax call: differences between v2 and v3

Tags: php, ajax, google-maps-api-3

I am upgrading a google maps v2 project to v3. It's gone well so far but I've hit a problem for which I've not yet been able to find a solution (though I do have a work-around).

Visitors to the map are able to click on a location, have the Lat & Long appear in an infoWindow and be able to save that data to an XML file. I had this working OK in v2.

It works in v3 too, but only if I remove all the Ajax checking, which seems dangerous.
In v2 I had:

```
        var request = GXmlHttp.create();

// open the request to storeMarker.php on server
request.open('GET', 'storeMarker.php' + getVars, true);
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
        // the request is complete
        var xmlDoc = request.responseXML;
        // retrieve the root document element (response)
        var responseNode = xmlDoc.documentElement;
        // retrieve the type attribute of the node
        var type = responseNode.getAttribute("type");

        // retrieve the content ofthe responseNode
        var content = responseNode.firstChild.nodeValue;

        //check to see if it was an error, or success
        if (type != 'success') {
            alert(content);
        } else {
            // create a new marker and add its info window
            var latlng = new GLatLng(parseFloat(lat), parseFloat(lng));
            var marker = makeTempMarker(latlng, content, bus);
            map.addOverlay(marker);
            map.closeInfoWindow();
        }
    }
```

Somehow the GXmlHttp.create() seems to have coped with the file I'm calling being 'storeMarker.php' and not XML at all. The storeMarker.php file DOES open an XML file (and successfully saves the new marker). This code came out of 'Beginning Google Maps Applications with PHP and Ajax' (Apress: Purvis, Sambells & Turner, 2006) which only applied to v2.

The GXmlHttp.create() is no longer available for v3, and I've used instead a short cross-browser function that opens an Ajax request (function not reproduced here):

```
    var request = getAjaxObject();
```

Now the JS chokes on the 'request.responseXML'. I have tried 'request.responseText', but (unsurprisingly) that doesn't work either.

My question is, what do I do instead ?

As I've said above, if I remove the response checking beyond the 'status == 200' check, and using appropriate v3 syntax the marker data gets saved and a temporary marker is duly displayed. But it doesn't feel 'safe'.

Comment: Why do you post your V2-code when you want to know why the V3-code didn't work?

Comment: [xml parsing from the demo gallery](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/xmlparsing/)

Comment: Because (so far) my V3 code is the same, except for the initial instantiation of the request. Sorry if I didn't make this clear.

Answer (score 0):

I have now discovered that the 'storeMarker.php' file should have had a header 'header('Content-Type: text/xml');'. (It got lost in translation). Putting this back has got me onto the next line of the script (!), but I hope i can work my own way out of the problem from here.